# Uploading Photo to existing album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am doing a test to try to upload photos to a user's profile. I was able to get it to upload a photo to the default app album by posting it to /me/photos; however, when I try to post another photo to that same album with the same method, it returns an OAuthException. Same thing happens when I try to upload to a separate existing album.

If I delete the app album, I can then upload again and it works, but as soon as I try to upload another, it fails.

I've tried it both with the .NET SDK and with the standard PHP SDK. Both give the same result.

**.NET SDK Code**

Here is the action I'm posting my form to:

```
public ActionResult UploadToDefaultAlbum(PhotoUploadModel model)
    {
        model = model ?? new PhotoUploadModel();

        if (model.IsPostback)
        {
            if (model.PhotoUpload != null)
            {
                var fb = new FacebookWebClient(model.AccessToken);
                dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

                parameters.title = model.Title;
                parameters.description = model.Title + " description";
                parameters.source =
                    new FacebookMediaObject {ContentType = model.PhotoUpload.ContentType, FileName = model.PhotoUpload.FileName}.
                        SetValue(GetFileBytes(model.PhotoUpload.InputStream));

                var result = fb.Post("/me/photos", parameters);
                ViewBag.Message = result;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "PhotoUpload is null";
            }
        }

        model.IsPostback = true;
        return View("Upload",model);
    }
```

And my HTML form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadToDefaultAlbum", "Photos", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"})) { 
<fieldset>
    <legend>Upload to default App album</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.InputFor(System.Web.Mvc.Html5.InputType.Text, x => x.Title)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PhotoUpload)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.InputFor(System.Web.Mvc.Html5.InputType.File, x => x.PhotoUpload)
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IsPostback)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AccessToken)
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
```

}

When a user loads the form page, I verify they have the user_photos and publish_stream permissions (using the CanvasAuthorize attribute).

Is there something I'm missing to allow me to upload to an existing album?

**PHP SDK Code**

I copied this code directly from https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/ and just set the variables at the top for my app.

```
<?php

   $app_id = "xxx";
   $app_secret = "xxx";
   $post_login_url = "https://localhost/facebookresearch/photoupload.php";
   $album_name = 'PHP Test Album';
   $album_description = 'YOUR_ALBUM_DESCRIPTION';

   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
   if(empty($code))
     {
       $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id 
       . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
       . "&scope=publish_stream";
       echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . 
       "'</script>");
   } 
   else {
     $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
     . "access_token?"
     . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
     . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
     . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
     . "&code=" . $code;
     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $access_token = $params['access_token'];

     // Create a new album
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
     . "access_token=". $access_token;

     $postdata = http_build_query(
     array(
      'name' => $album_name,
      'message' => $album_description
        )
      );
     $opts = array('http' =>
     array(
      'method'=> 'POST',
      'header'=>
        'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'content' => $postdata
      )
     );
     $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
     $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, 
       $context));

     // Get the new album ID
     $album_id = $result->id;

     //Show photo upload form and post to the Graph URL
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $album_id
       . "/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;
     echo '<html><body>';
     echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
     .$graph_url. ' "method="POST">';
     echo 'Adding photo to album: ' . $album_name .'<br/><br/>';
     echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
     echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
     echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
     echo '<input name="message" type="text"
        value=""><br/><br/>';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br/>';
     echo '</form>';
     echo '</body></html>';
  }
```

?>

The response is:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

It creates the album, but can't upload the photo to it. So it seems there is either a setting I have wrong in my app or a bug in FB. I would guess the former, but can't figure out what it might be.

Would it make a difference that the app is in sandbox mode and I'm using a test user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears this is only an issue when using an app in sandbox mode. I switched my app out of sandbox mode and it all worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

It is neither a bug in fb nor a bug in php or csharp sdk. It is the expected behavior.

You cannot upload photos to albums that app doesn't own.

Comment: Why would it give me the same error when I try to upload a second photo to /me/photos in the app's photo album?